# How can I translate some JavaScript code into Mathematica code?

Tags: core-language, data-structures

I am a programmer and would like to understand another field outside of the procedural thinking of `if-else` and `for`.

I would like to understand ...
Would if possible ...
Is there a formula that can explain these steps?
So ... is ... this

#### Example 1, JavaScript

```
var  block_word_list = [
"aaaaaaa", "jsdkjfids", "jijaswwww", "bebbbebeb"
];

function check(){
  var b = false;
  var a = document.getElementById("inputA").value;
  for (let index = 0; index < block_word_list.length; index++) {
    if(block_word_list[index] === a ){
      b = true;
      break;
    };

  }
  console.log(b);
  if(b){
    inputInvalid();
  }
}

function inputInvalid(){
document.getElementById("inputA").style.border = "2px solid red";
}
```

**Example 2, without JavaScript**

```
'f' is 'expression' to function state "block_word_list"
'n' is 'expression' to function "check"
'k' is 'expression' to "parameter" of function state '"block_word_list"'
'z' is 'expression' to "parameter" of function state 'check' 
'z' have 'z has this variables' 

1. b as 'false;'
2. a as 'document.getElementById("inputA").value;' and have this 'rule'
3. 'rule 1'  'for (let index = 0; index < block_word_list.length; index++) {'  and...  'rule 2'
4. 'rule 2' have ' if(block_word_list[index] === a ){' with 'rule 3'
5. 'rule 3' have  'b = true;' and... 'rule 4'
6. 'rule 4' have  'break' and... 'rule 5'
7. 'rule 5' have '};' and... 'rule 6'
8. 'rule 6' have  'if(b){' and... 'rule 7'
9. 'rule 7' have  'inputInvalid();' and... 'rule 8'
10. 'rule 8' have '}' and... 'rule 9'
11. 'rule 9' have '}' and... end
```

#### Expression/Step to Mathematica

> f = n(k, z)/ k = z ( 6v )

#### Note

```
> 'f' is function of block_word_list
> 'n' is function of check if block_word_list true or false.
> 'k' is constant of 'f'
> 'z' is contant of 'n'
> '/' is about... symbol ^------
> = is 'equal'
> '6 v' is 'variables' of z.
```

Is this right? How would I translate this into Mathematica?

Comment: Hi Pedro, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. As it stands, this question is quite unclear. Please reword it into something more understandable - for a start, please read the [How to ask a good question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) document. If this question is not reworded, it may be closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I started earning my living through computer programming in 1958. I have coded in over 20 programming languages. I have been using Mathematica since 1995. I know enough about JavaScript that I think I could translate your example 1 code into Mathematica. However, everything you posted starting with example 2 is gibberish to me. It has no resemblance to Mathematica code as I know it, so I have to say it is not at correct.

Comment: I said "I think I could" -- that means I might be able to do it, not that I am ready and willing to do it. So sorry, but no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code not only is in JavaScript but it also interacts with the DOM in a web browser. Needless to say this is very different in Mathematica. This is my interpretation of it:

```
blockedWordQ[word_String] := 
 MemberQ[{"aaaaaaa", "jsdkjfids", "jijaswwww", "bebbbebeb"}, word]

DynamicModule[{inputA = "", blockedWord = False},
 Dynamic@Framed[
   InputField[
    Dynamic[
     inputA, (inputA = #; blockedWord = blockedWordQ[inputA]) &], 
    String, ContinuousAction -> True],
   FrameStyle -> If[blockedWord, Red, None]]]
```

Comment: Thanks... Really, thanks ! ;D